# Angular 4 OnClick Tab

Tags: angular, components

I'm using Angular 4, 
in the main component I put a tabset with 3 tabs, then I created other three components with their code. Now how can I detect the event when I click on a tab, how can I do this?

main component

```
<tabset>
    <tab  heading="first">
        <app-first #first></app-first>
    </tab>
    <tab  heading="second">
        <app-second #second></app-second>
    </tab>
    <tab  heading="third">
      <app-third #third></app-third>
    </tab>
</tabset>
```

I mean if like I do `(click)='function()'`